# Is anyone using tabletop_object_detector?

Tags: ros, tabletop-object-detector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wondered if anyone is using the tabletop_object_detector package. According to the ROS wiki it's not been updated since groovy.

A few questions I had -

1. How easy would it be to use this package in Indigo?
2. I'm running into a lot of dependency issues (Especially since this package has not been catkinized) Is there a way to solve this easily?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221098/is-anyone-using-tabletop_object_detector?/) by [Sidd](https://answers.ros.org/users/22657/sidd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2015-11-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wanglan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23987/wanglan/) on 2016-04-06**:
Hello! I met the same question,have you solve it?

**Comment by [Sidd](https://answers.ros.org/users/22657/sidd/) on 2016-06-23**:
Sorry for the late reply, but no I was not able to make much progress. I realized that there were too many dependencies that were outdated and experimental.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For anyone who wants to use an object detector ros now has a nice new package for this - http://wiki.ros.org/find_object_2d .

---

Originally posted by [Sidd](https://answers.ros.org/users/22657/sidd/) with karma: 155 on 2016-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2